# Why does this quick sort not work at all?

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, quicksort

Basically the program asked the user for a range for (X,Y,Z) coordinates, and is asked for the number of points he wishes to generate. The values are passed on to the object class, where the quicksort algorithm takes place. Once the values are passed to the writeData class, they proceed to print in the file heres an example output : Where the number of points is 2(2 sets of xyz coordinates)
and the range is 1 (from positive infinity to negative infinity)

```
(0.01916820621893911),(0.7031915303569696),(0.8313160912583086)
(-0.9343528090486088),(0.015998642441189093),(0.49980249751031924)
```

As you can tell by the output, it is not sorted at all, why is this problem occurring, if my algorithm seems to work. I have tried debugging for the past hour or so, to no avail. Also, since quick sorting mufti dimensional arrays is not really used as often, this was the only algorithm i could attempt to use. Anyways, some or any input would go a mile long way on helping me fix this dilemma!

Main program (Short and sweet) :

```
import java.io.*;
public class test {
  public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {
  BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

  testplus1 c = new testplus1();
  double dataPoints [][] = new double [3][10000];
  int numPoints;
  int range;
  String input;

  System.out.println("Please enter a range");
  input = myInput.readLine();
  range = Integer.parseInt(input);
  System.out.println("Please enter the number of points");
  input = myInput.readLine();
  numPoints = Integer.parseInt(input);
  c.setNumPoints(numPoints);
  c.setArray(dataPoints);
  c.setRange(range);

  c.fillArray(dataPoints,range,numPoints);
  } 
}
```

Object class

```
import java.io.*;

public class testplus1 {
  private static double [][] myDataPoints;
  private static double [][] sd;
  private static int myRange;
  private static int myNumPoints;

  public testplus1() throws IOException{
    myNumPoints = getNumPoints();
    myRange = getRange();
    myDataPoints = getArray();
    fillArray(myDataPoints,myRange,myNumPoints);
  }

  public void fillArray(double [][] myDataPoints,int myRange, int myNumPoints) throws IOException{
     for(int i = 0; i < myNumPoints; i++) {
      myDataPoints[0][i] =  2* (double)(Math.random () * myRange) - myRange; 
      myDataPoints[1][i] =  2* (double)(Math.random () * myRange) - myRange; 
      myDataPoints[2][i] =  2* (double)(Math.random () * myRange) - myRange; 
     sort(myDataPoints,0,0,myDataPoints.length-1);
     }
  }

 public double[][] sort(double[][] array, int key, int down, int top) throws IOException{
      double[][] a = new double[array.length][3];
      System.arraycopy(array,0,a,0, a.length);

       int i = down;
       int j = top;

       double x = a[(down + top) / 2][key];

        do {
            while (a[i][key] < x) {
                i++;
            }

            while (a[j][key] > x) {
                j--;
            }

            if (i <= j) {
                double[] temp = new double[a[i].length];

                for (int y = 0; y < a[i].length; y++) {
                    temp[y] = a[i][y];
                    a[i][y] = a[j][y];
                    a[j][y] = temp[y];
                }

                i++;
                j--;
            }
        } while (i <= j);

        if (down < j) {
            a = sort(a, key, down, j);
        }

        if (i < top) {
            a = sort(a, key, i, top);
        }
        writeData(myDataPoints);
        return a;

 }
  public static void writeData(double [][] myDataPoints) throws IOException {
    PrintWriter printWriter = (new PrintWriter ("test123"));
    for(int i = 0; i < myNumPoints; i++) {
      printWriter.println("(" + myDataPoints[0][i] + "),(" + myDataPoints[1][i] + "),(" + myDataPoints[2][i] + ")"); 
    }
    printWriter.close();
  }  

  public void setArray(double [][] dataPoints) {
    myDataPoints = dataPoints;
  }

  public double [][] getArray() {
    return myDataPoints;
  }

  public  void setNumPoints(int numPoints) {
    myNumPoints = numPoints;
  }

  public  int getNumPoints() {
    return myNumPoints; 
  }

  public void setRange(int range) {
    myRange = range; 
  }

  public int getRange() {
    return myRange; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your `sort` method.

```
public double[][] sort(double[][] array, int key, int down, int top) throws IOException{
    double[][] a = new double[array.length][3];
    System.arraycopy(array,0,a,0, a.length);
```

You create a new array `a` and perform all the operations on it instead of the original input array (changes to the original array would be automatically visible outside the method). Finally, you return `a`, which would work, but in `fillArray`...

```
sort(myDataPoints,0,0,myDataPoints.length-1);
```

You don't assign it to any variable. The only thing that gets changed is a *copy* of `myDataPoints`, not `mydataPoints` itself.

Comment: With that logic in mind then, could I not just scratch array a, and use the array im passing on instead, which would eventually return array; instead of return a;

Comment: I'd recommend trying using the current version first, and actually using the array returned by sort. That way you know whether your algorithm is otherwise correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Arrays.sort`. Use `myDataPoints` as first parameter and a custom comparator as second parameter. For more info, check the documentation at [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[], java.util.Comparator)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29).

If you give me more information about how you want to sort the values, I can give you an example of the comparator.

Comment: I need to sort using quick sort, as this is what my assignment states.